# AWS Interactive Video Service - ivs.AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am following the AWS tutorial on how to set up the new video streaming product IVC https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ivs/latest/userguide/GSIVS.html

I set up a IAM user with the following permissions

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "ivs:CreateChannel"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
   ]
}
```

But when I try to create a channel with logged in as the above mentioned IAM user I get the error

```
ivs.AccessDeniedException: 
User: arn:aws:iam::532654645459:user/alex-iam is not authorized to perform: 
ivs:CreateChannel on resource: *
```

Am I missing something? Here are is screenshots for the policy setup.

[image: policy setup for my IAM user]

Comment: I am having the same issue. Tried it with your policy and the policy provided by Amazon: https://ivs-streaming.workshop.aws/getting-started/self-paced/account.html
No success...

Comment: UPDATE: that seemed a transient issue, I didn't change anything and 1 week later I got permission for `ivs:CreateChannel`, unfortunately now I lack permissions to perform ` ivs:ListChannels`

Comment: once I added `ivs:ListChannels` to the policy and the permission now works as expected

Answer (score 1):

(OP here) The solution that worked for me was to change the policy to grant all permissions to IVS for IAM user as follows:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "ivs:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Everything worked fine afterward (create channels, list channels, view channels details).

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this issue,  best is to reach out to  AWS Support Center via  “Account and billing support”. For details about the case, select “Account” for the Type and “Other Account Issues” for the Category. As for the subject and description, please provide as many details about the error as possible, such as the error code above.

What could also be helpful is to (especially on a fresh AWS account) is to spin up p/ launch an EC2 instance (Micro or whatever) and spin it back down. Try using IVS after that and see if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

What type of account are you using ( free tier, educate account)?
In educate account IAM users do no have access to some services. This might be on of the issues.

Comment: I just made a new fresh account just for this use case, so I guess is a free tier

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by add policy to the lambda function
Go to the AWS IAM page and navigate to Role.

And then find the role for your lambda function and click add permission button
and create inline policy

There, you can create and attach policy to role.
as you written on above.

After that, your functions will work well